# C# code throwing exception while not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I'm working in Visual Studio 14.  When I initially open the solution, a catch block in my application is triggered and a messagebox displays as if the app were running.

The exception occurs when the app tries to get a connectionstring from my app.config.

Why would it throw an error if the app is not being executed?  It even does it periodically while I'm working elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Because it *is* running, in the designer.

Comment: As @rory.ap says. Which is why you should be extra careful about putting any code in UI component constructors.

Comment: How about posting some information about the actual error? Maybe the message box text? Something!

Comment: @Juan Sorry.  I didn't think the actual code would be relevant since my question is more about why visual studio would show the dialog when it isn't running, not why the code itself is failing.

Comment: @rory.ap, Thanks.  I didn't realize it went to this extent.  I've never seen an actual dialog popup as a result of code running during design of the code.

Comment: The fact that the try catch block fires is a clear indication that the code IS running (as @rory.ap mentioned). Designers need to run the code in order to do certain things. This is specially true with UI components like forms. As for the dialog, that's just how VS is handling the situation internally. Either way, this is an unfortunate side effect of using designers. I've had situations like this in the past where I had to put workarounds in code just to be able to use the designers.

Comment: @Juan Ah, okay.  I had no idea the designer would go so far.  FWIW, this is a class whose constructor makes a call to the repo and fetches some data from a SQL database.  The behavior is fairly sporadic.  Thank you for the info!

Comment: That makes sense actually. It probably can't find the configuration file and that is why it fails. I haven't done this kind of thing in ages but if I remember well, there is a property IsDesignMode or something like that that you can check. That's one of the workarounds I mentioned before. Good luck!